# $H_1,H_2$ subgroups such that $|H_2|/|H_1|$ is a prime. There is no subgroups stricly between them.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How could one begin by demonstrating this? I really can't think of a strategy to leave.

Let $G$ a finite group. Let $H_1$, $H_2$ subgroups of $G$ such that $H_1\subset H_2$ and $|H_2|/|H_1|$ is prime. Show that there is no subgroup stricly between $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: Hint: if $n_2/n_1$ is prime, then there is no $m$ such that $n_1<m<n_2$, $n_1\mid m$ and $m\mid n_2$.

Comment: Without changing the question, we can assume $H_2 = G$.

Consider the special case where $H_1$ is the trivial subgroup. Then the claim reduces to the fact that a group of prime order has no nontrivial proper subgroups. If you don't know how to prove this yet, definitely tackle this first! Hint: Lagrange.

The general proof is actually exactly the same, if you write it out carefully. Hint: if $K$ is a subgroup strictly between $H_1$  and $G$, what relationships does Lagrange's theorem give you between the orders of $H_1$, $K$, and $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be subgroup between subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$.So, $H_1 \leq H \leq H_2$.
Then, $[H_2:H][H:H_1]=[H_2:H_1]=|H_2|/|H_1|$ which is prime.
So $[H_2:H]=1$ or $[H_1:H]=1$
So $H_2=H$ or $H_1=H$

Answer (score 1):

**(Big) hint.** Let $K$ be a subgroup such that $H_1\subset K\subset H_2$. We know that $[H_2:H_1]=p$ for $p$ prime. What can the indices

$$[H_2:K]\quad \text{and} \quad [K:H_1]$$

now be? (Use the tower law for subgroups.)

Comment: But I have a question: If $H_1 \subset H_2$ and $H_1,H_2$ subgroups of a group $G$, then $H_1$ is a subgroup of $H_2$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Just check the definition of a subgroup.